# Disable everything else on windows phone tablet

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

**TL;DR;**
How do I disable everything on windows phone that a user can use to "get out of my app"

**Long version**
I'm developing a app for a table running windows phone.
 This tablet will be available to general public so they can choose which kind of service they want (like "open new account", "talk to the manager" and so on). Because of that I would like to disable everything on the tablet (home button, close button...) so a miss guided user wont be able to close my app.
How do I do that? (Of course I intend to provide a "Close app" button that will require a password of some kind...)

Comment: There's no tablets running Windows Phone, so I'd highly doubt you're developing a app for such.

Comment: You might be able to fix this using a physical constraint: just make the back, home and search buttons not available by covering them.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do what you want with Windows Phone. There is no ability to, in software, block access to the start or search buttons.

As indicated in other answers, you can override the back button but if you prevented the app from going to the home screen you would be unable to get the application certified (you could still sideload to the device, or distribute through the company store).

You may be better served considering an RT device (with Windows 8.1 in KIOSK mode) or Windows 8 Embedded Handheld (which is based on Windows Phone 8).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to change the behavior of the back button by doing the following.

Place this in your phone:PhoneApplicationPage tag ie the header of the page.

**XAML**

```
BackKeyPress="PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress"
```

In the code behind.

**C#**

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

However it is not possible to capture the home key pressed and search key pressed events. You could try messing with the "Application_Deactivated" method in the App.xaml.cs so that when the application is deactivated...it is not? That could get messy and I've never done it before. Just an idea. Good luck.

Comment: Overriding the OnBackKeyPress method is a much better way to override the BackKeyPress, than subscribing to the event.

Comment: I appreciate the advice but could you explain to me why? I am new to windows phone.